# How can you make animate faster and faster?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can you make animate faster and faster?

You can see by looking at the code. I've always had the animation effect at the same speed. But I wanted to have an animation effect that was slow at first, and then fast. How can you do that? I also want to know how to be slow at first, then faster in the middle, and then slower again.

```
$('.menu').animate({left : '0px'}, 500);
```

Comment: The third argument of the `animate()` method is `easing`, which defines the animation's style of progression. The default (`"swing"`) starts slow, speeds up, and ends slow, just as you describe. To allow for additional options, you can include [jQuery UI](https://api.jqueryui.com/easings/).  Please note though, that if you're only looking to animate an item's position, you should definitely consider using CSS animation, specifically the `transform` property.

Comment: _How can you make animate faster and faster?_ You accomplish with the `easing` parameter of the `.animate()` method. You'll need a plug in or jQueryUI.

Comment: `ease-in` is slow then fast

Answer (score 1):

I think those animations effects you mentioned are as follows, you can cross check to see whether these are the intended effects.

`ease-in`: slow at the beginning, fast/abrupt at the end;

`ease-out`: fast/abrupt at the beginning, slow at the end;

`ease-in-out`:  the change happens slowly both at the beginning and end, and speeds up only in the middle somewhere.

More refers to
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-timing-function.asp or 
https://css-tricks.com/ease-out-in-ease-in-out/

However, to use JQuery animate function, you can combine any of the effect above with jquery animate function like below
`$('.menu').animate({left : '0px'}, 500,"easein");` , with tweaks of the syntax.

This will only works if you provide a plugin that provides the easing function. More on http://api.jquery.com/animate/ .

Comment: While I do believe that CSS animations are preferable where possible, I'm not sure this answers the question. OP asked about  `animate()`, tagging solely `jQuery` and `JavaScript`; your answer doesn't touch on any of those.

Comment: Sorry I have not made myself clear. Updated my answer.

Comment: The CSS animations that you've mentioned and linked documentation for however, do not relate to jQuery in the slightest. Some may share a common name, but jQuery does not use CSS animations as `easing` arguments. Your answer touches on the right path with the jQuery documentation but the first half is quite misleading.

Comment: The way OP structured his question makes me thinks he does not know the animation effect that has already available in CSS, that can be cross-used in animate function as well, which is why leads me to show him the animation effects that can fulfill his needs. But yea jQuery will have different syntax to refer for the names being used by removing the hyphens.